# Granularity in Star Schema leads to multiple values in Fact Table?

Tags: data-warehouse, datamodel, star-schema

I'm trying to understand star schema at the moment & struggling a lot with granularity.

Say I have a fact table that has session_id, user_id, order_id, product_id and I want to roll-up to sessions by user by week (keeping in mind that not every session would lead to an order or a product & the DW needs to track the sessions for non-purchasing users as well as those who purchase).

I can see no reason to track order_ids or session_ids in the fact table so it would become something like:

week_date, user_id, total_orders, total_sessions ...

But how would I then track product_ids if a user makes more than one purchase in a week? I assume I can't keep multiple product ids in an array (eg: "20/02/2012","5","3","PR01,PR32,PR22")?

I'm thinking it may have to be kept at 'every session' level but that could lead to a very large amount of data.  How would you implement granularity for an example such as above?

Answer (score 0):

Dimensional modelling required Dimensions as well as Facts.

You need a Date/Calendar dimension, which includes columns like this:

```
calendar (id,cal_date,cal_year,cal_month,...)
```

The "grain" of your fact table is the key to data storage. If you have transactions, then the transaction should be the grain, and you store one row per transaction. Use proper (integer) surrogate keys to your dimensions, and your table won't be as large as you fear.

Now you can write a query like this, to sum sales of product by year:

```
select product_name,cal_year,sum(purchase_amount)
from   fact_whatever
       inner join calendar on id = fact_whatever.calendar_id
       inner join product on id = fact_whatever.product_id
group  by product_name,cal_year
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't have the rep to upvote yet but this is very useful!